# How to disable/suppress Resharper code analysis (Roslyn) for specific lines?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, resharper, suppress-warnings

Reshaper does not recognize my type alias "DataType":

```
Type 'DataType' is not defined.
```

[image]

However, "DataType" **is defined** in my project settings and the program works correctly:

[image]

=> How can I suppress that specific warning (without disabling other, possibly justified data type warnings)?

I tried to

A. Wrap the corresponding lines with

```
#Disable Warning BC30002
...
#Enable Warning BC30002
```

B. Put

```
'ReSharper disable All
```

at top of the file.

C. 
    #Region "No Resharper"
    ...
    #End Region

D. `<SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "All")>`

None of them worked so far. I would expect a suppression option in the quick fix suggestions. But there is none.

I use VisualStudio 15.7.3 and Resharper 2018.1.2

Related questions:

- [Is there a way to disable resharper code analysis for a single file using a comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748741/is-there-a-way-to-disable-resharper-code-analysis-for-a-single-file-using-a-comm)
- [Disable all Resharper warnings with a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854701/disable-all-resharper-warnings-with-a-comment)

Comment: Here's my opinion. I think the reason why ReSharper isn't using this as a valid data type alias declaration is that you're abusing a feature that is meant to do something else. The whole UI mentions "namespaces", not "using directives". As such it isn't surprising that ReSharper isn't considering these *namespaces* as alias declarations. For sure, you should tell Jetbrains about this, but I don't think there are any *supported* and *good* ways to get ReSharper to stop complaining.

Comment: If you disable ReSharper via Tools | Options | ReSharper Ultimate | Suspend now - will the squiggle still appear in the editor? I am asking about that since the light bulb and the quick fix pop-up definitely comes from Roslyn, not ReSharper. ReSharper does not show the light bulb in the middle of the editor, just on or next to the gutter mark.